# Laravel 5: Retrieve JSON array from $request

Tags: laravel-5

I'm a Laravel newbie and I'm converting a php/jquery app to Laravel. The original code used a JSON array with an ajax POST, which was retrieved like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

I'm doing much the same thing on the POST side, but I don't see any data coming through in my Laravel $request collection. Is there something special that I need to do to retrieve JSON data structured like this:

```
[
    { "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }, 
    { "name": "Dave", "location": "Lancaster" }
]
```

Here is my jQuery ajax POST code (with hard coded data)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/people",
    data: '[{ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }, { "name": "Dave", "location": "Lancaster" }]',
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
        $('#save_message').html(data.message);
    } 
});
```

Here is the code in my Controller that receives the POST

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

But all I get is:

> []

Any ideas on how I can retreive my data?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You need to change your Ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/people",
    data: '[{ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }, { "name": "Dave", "location": "Lancaster" }]',
    contentType: "json",
    processData: false,
    success:function(data) {
        $('#save_message').html(data.message);
    } 
});
```

change the `dataType` to `contentType` and add the `processData` option.

To retrieve the JSON payload from your controller, use:

```
dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));
```

instead of

```
dd($request->all());
```

Comment: Sadly, I still don't get any data in my Laravel Controller - just []. However I can see that the headers change from  **Form Data** to **Request Payload**

Comment: I have updated my response, you need to change the way you get the input in the controller, too.

Comment: I've been back to this comment many times over the last few years, and I really appreciate it. Just wanted to say thanks.

Answer (score 36):

```
 $postbody='';
 // Check for presence of a body in the request
 if (count($request->json()->all())) {
     $postbody = $request->json()->all();
 }
```

This is how it's done in laravel 5.2 now.

Comment: Thank you so much :), I was trying to use this with the JS fetch API

Answer (score 8):

Just a mention with jQuery v3.2.1 and Laravel 5.6.

**Case 1:** The JS object posted directly, like:

```
$.post("url", {name:'John'}, function( data ) {
});
```

Corresponding Laravel PHP code should be:

```
parse_str($request->getContent(),$data); //JSON will be parsed to object $data
```

**Case 2**: The JSON string posted, like:

```
$.post("url", JSON.stringify({name:'John'}), function( data ) {
});
```

Corresponding Laravel PHP code should be:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

Comment: how do you parse in php controller `{name:'John'}` the name? `$data->name` ?

Comment: What does the true do here? I couldn't figure it out from the documentation  on json_decode.

Answer (score 5):

You can use getContent() method on Request object.

```
$request->getContent() //json as a string.
```

Comment: Answers should always come with some explantion

Answer (score 4):

As of Laravel 5.2+, you can fetch it directly with `$request->input('item')` as well.

> ## Retrieving JSON Input Values
>
> When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the
>   JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of
>   the request is properly set to application/json. You may even use
>   "dot" syntax to dig deeper into JSON arrays:
>
> $name = $request->input('user.name');

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests

As noted above, the content-type header must be set to `application/json` so the jQuery ajax call would need to include `contentType: "application/json",`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/people",
    data: '[{ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }, { "name": "Dave", "location": "Lancaster" }]',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success:function(data) {
        $('#save_message').html(data.message);
    } 
});
```

By fixing the AJAX call, `$request->all()` should work.

Comment: then how can i parse `"name" and "location"` after `$request->all()`?

Answer (score 0):

My jQuery ajax settings:

```
        $.ajax({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: params,
        success: function (resp){
            ....
        },
        error: responseFunc
    });
```

And now i am able to get the request via `$request->all()` in Laravel

```
dataType: "json"
```

is the important part in the ajax request to handle the response as an json object and not string.