# Decode json data to array and access the array in PHP(Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I am trying to submit my form input as json format. After decoding json data  into an array I can't access array.

```
{
    "info": {
        "q_title": "hello",
        "q_description": "ddd",
        "q_visibility": "1",
        "start_date": "Thu, 05 Oct 2017 06:11:00 GMT"
    }
}
```

This is my json data. My Laravel controller is following:

```
public function store_quiz(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        $input = $arrayName = array(
            'title' => $data["info"]["q_title"], 
        );

        CreateQuiz::create($input);

        $redirect = '/';
        return $redirect;
    }
```

Unfortunately `$data["info"]["q_title"]` returns NULL. How to access "q_tittle" of my json??

Comment: can you print_r()$request->getContent());.may be that is null

Comment: show us $data, so we can see your array

Comment: Your request body isnt a valid json

Comment: what `$request->getContent()` returns. Is it JSON encoded string?
Moreover are you sure your JSON encoded string always has the above attributes which you are trying to access ?

Answer (score 4):

just access your data after `json_decode` like this without a second argument.

```
$data->info->q_title
```

and by using the second argument as true, which will convert your object into an array.

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContents(),true) //then use
$data['info']['q_title']
```

and if you are not getting anything in `$request->getContents()` then the problem lies in the request that you are sending.

Also, check this two links for how to retrieve JSON payload

[Laravel 5: Retrieve JSON array from $request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005815/laravel-5-retrieve-json-array-from-request)

[Posting JSON To Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219482/posting-json-to-laravel)

Comment: don't know why I m getting -2 in this.

Comment: @Dhaval.he given true so When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.that may be the reason down voted

Comment: @DhavalPurohit take a look into documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php (-;

Comment: ok then the problem should lie in `$request->getContent()` @iCoders

Comment: not sure .so $data output only we can decide.without that i cant comment any think without looking code and outptu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `$request->getContent()` content is different from your example, because for me it works.

Try to check what you have in `$request->getContent()`.

Example:

```
<?php
$source = '{
    "info": {
        "q_title": "hello",
        "q_description": "ddd",
        "q_visibility": "1",
        "start_date": "Thu, 05 Oct 2017 06:11:00 GMT"
    }
}';
$data = json_decode($source, true);
echo $data['info']['q_title'];
```

Comment: Yes. Actually problem lies in  $request->getContent(). @Neodan

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

My data was saved in `var data` in jQuery.

To post data I used

```
$.ajax({  .... data: {data: data} .... });
```

instead of

```
 $.ajax({  .... data: data .... });
```

So I got unexpected value from `$request->getContent()`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more Laravel style method of doing this:

```
public function store_quiz(Request $request)
{
    $input = $arrayName = array(
        'title' => $request->input('info.q_title'), 
    );

    CreateQuiz::create($input);

    $redirect = '/';
    return $redirect;
}
```

And ensure your javascript app sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Laravel will `json_decode()` it for you.

---

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests (Retrieving JSON Input Values)