# Laravel multiple image with resize and data via api

Tags: laravel, multipartform-data, image-resizing

I'm writing API for one mobile app.
App will send multiple data with 1 or 2 images using POST method. For single data my api works without problem. I have to resize every image and store resized to `thumbs` folder, original to `images` folder of server.

Here is my code

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'contact_id' => 'required',
        'melod_id' => 'required',
        'disease_id' => 'required',
        'treatment_id' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    if ($request->has('photo')){
        $photo = $request->file('photo');
        $input['imagename'] = 'stat-'.time().'.'.$photo->extension();
        $imagename = $input['imagename'];
        $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbs');
        $img = Image::make($photo->path());
        $img->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename);
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $photo->move($destinationPath, $imagename);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['photo'] = $imagename;
    }
    if ($request->has('photo_2')){
        $photo = $request->file('photo_2');
        $input['imagename2'] = 'shir-'.time().'.'.$photo->extension();
        $imagename2 = $input['imagename2'];
        $destinationPath = public_path('/thumbs');
        $img = Image::make($photo->path());
        $img->resize(150, 150, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        })->save($destinationPath.'/'.$imagename2);
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $photo->move($destinationPath, $imagename2);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['photo'] = $imagename;
        $input['photo_2'] = $imagename2;
    }
    Statistics::create($input);

    $stat = Statistics::where('contact_id','=', $request->contact_id)->orderby('id', 'desc')->first();
    return $stat;
}
```

**When mobile app send me multiple data in array like beloved how I can store it?**

```
[
  {
    "contact_id": "15",
    "melod_id": "1",
    "disease_id": "1",
    "treatment_id": "2",
    "status": "1",
    "hasAphid": "0",
    "date": "2021-10-10",
    "photo": "filename1.jpg",
    "photo_2": "filename2.jpg",
},
{
    "contact_id": "15",
    "melod_id": "2",
    "disease_id": "1",
    "treatment_id": "2",
    "status": "1",
    "hasAphid": "1",
    "date": "2021-10-10"
    "photo": "filename4.jpg",
    "photo_2": "filename5.jpg",
}
]
```

Comment: what is your question? you mean how to do it if it has more than 2 images?

Comment: No when mobile app sends to API multiple data in array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5: Retrieve JSON array from $request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005815/laravel-5-retrieve-json-array-from-request)

Comment: No this is AJAX request, in my case mobile app send to api data and files in one array, and sometimes i can send me multiple arrays.