# How to fetch data from a json with laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I premise that I'm new to the Laravel environment.

I have this JSON file in the database

```
{
    "48:CE:B8:09:7D:AD": ["-91"],
    "70:61:91:66:6B:1E": ["-81", "-69", "-79", "-65", "-74"],
    "4B:6F:42:53:EB:82": ["-84", "-73", "-81"],
    "77:87:80:27:2B:31": ["-83", "-70", "-82", "-71", "-79", "-71", "-79", "-71", "-80", "-72"],
    "43:FD:25:20:5A:7B": ["-76", "-84", "-76", "-88", "-77", "-86"],
    "C1:04:08:03:3C:05": ["-73"],
    "7F:D2:44:60:82:BD": ["-88", "-79", "-88"],
    "FE:47:DA:73:90:29": ["-55", "-43", "-59", "-35", "-46", "-38", "-49"],
    "62:46:58:C8:A9:9A": ["-68", "-77", "-68"],
    "68:13:E4:00:12:30": ["-68", "-81"],
    "4E:0D:D6:41:77:FA": ["-68", "-77", "-68", "-76", "-68", "-79", "-71"],
    "71:B0:03:A6:17:A5": ["-82", "-73", "-81", "-73"],
    "19:F2:64:21:35:B5": ["-74", "-65", "-77", "-69", "-78", "-69"],
    "5C:D5:BA:32:06:AD": ["-86"],
    "11:91:3D:57:0E:F0": ["-90", "-82"],
    "44:08:E7:5C:56:B3": ["-89", "-80"],
    "58:99:6F:53:65:C8": ["-77", "-85"],
    "54:3C:61:D8:5B:DD": ["-88", "-79"],
    "59:02:8C:78:5D:E1": ["-85", "-73", "-82", "-69", "-84", "-75", "-83", "-71"],
    "64:F0:DC:95:6E:16": ["-86", "-78"],
    "71:E5:42:BA:19:F4": ["-91", "-77", "-86", "-73", "-84", "-74", "-84"],
    "E1:63:14:57:89:25": ["-48", "-57", "-38", "-47"],
    "57:7D:E9:6F:06:24": ["-85"],
    "56:B2:4B:5B:7E:2E": ["-88", "-80"],
    "64:3D:02:D4:ED:4E": ["-76", "-64", "-72"],
    "0C:93:8F:E5:C6:2A": ["-76", "-66"],
    "3F:47:42:77:BD:9A": ["-64", "-83"],
    "3C:46:5E:20:9A:FE": ["-79", "-57", "-74"],
    "67:58:EE:A8:9D:CC": ["-64", "-80"],
    "C4:A5:DF:24:05:7E": ["-65"],
    "79:B8:3B:90:31:12": ["-89", "-71", "-88", "-75"],
    "75:8E:FE:9B:69:DA": ["-93"],
    "49:BE:B0:74:7A:71": ["-66", "-82"],
    "55:33:20:52:E1:EC": ["-75"],
    "45:D3:80:F3:A4:59": ["-79", "-71"],
    "44:CA:8A:EF:31:45": ["-92", "-78"],
    "5F:0D:99:F8:EE:94": ["-83"]
}
```

and I would like to get only some MAC addresses and respective RSSI values using Laravel.
My Model is the following:

```
class DataFromRasp extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['device'];

    protected $casts = ['device' => 'array'];

}
```

And my controller:

```
class DataFromRaspController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data=DataFromRasp::all();
        return view('backend.auth.user.dictionary', compact("data"));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
    }

    public function show(DataFromRasp $dataFromRasp)
    {
        
    }

    public function edit(DataFromRasp $dataFromRasp)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, DataFromRasp $dataFromRasp)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy(DataFromRasp $dataFromRasp)
    {
        //
    }

    public function getDict(Request $request)
    {   
        $data = $request->get('jsondata');
        $data = json_decode($data, true);
        DataFromRasp::create(['device' => $data]);

        return back()->with('success', 'Data successfully store in json format.');
    }
}
```

The getDict() function receives the JSON from a raspberry and saves it in the DB.

The structure of the DB table is as in figure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeLvM.jpg

I need the values of the MAC addresses "E1:63:14:57:89:25" and "FE:47:DA:73:90:29", how can I get them?

Comment: this question might be what you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005815/laravel-5-retrieve-json-array-from-request

Comment: This is more array related than Laravel related. Do you know how to access arrays? (If you don't, the PHP manual has a page on [Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with a section on "_Accessing array elements with square bracket syntax_" further down)

Comment: @brombeer it is also Laravel related because I don't know how to display the data on a view in Laravel

Comment: That would be subject for a new question then, this question is about getting specific data from an array